# Result in single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sum of each parameter as column adding in my parameter table 
table structure is of two columns ParamaterId and ResultValue
Value of table is

```
ParameterId ResultValue
2D/Ao Root Diam 0.03154840000000
AVA (VTI)   0.00016937690000
AVA (VTI)   0.00016937690000
2D/Ao Root Diam 0.03473202000000
AVA (VTI)   0.00006636187000
AVA (VTI)   0.00006755497000
```

I want to show ParameterId as Column Heading and Sum of ResultValue

```
AVA (VTI)             2D/Ao Root Diam
Sum(ResultValue)       Sum(ResultValue)
```

Below query producing correct resutl but the result is not is a single row, I need output should be in single row

```
AVA (VTI)          2D/Ao Root Diam
.573844582491253138     0
0                     18.5821659893339723
```

```
select 
    sum (case when ParameterId = 'AVA (VTI)' then (ResultValue) else 0 end) as 'AVA (VTI)',
    sum(case when ParameterId = '2D/Ao Root Diam' then (ResultValue) else 0 end) as '2D/Ao Root Diam'
   from DBCREATORS.Parameter as P
where ParameterId 
in ('AVA (VTI)', '2D/Ao Root Diam')
   group by ParameterId
```

Desired Result should be

```
AVA (VTI)              2D/Ao Root Diam
.573844582491253138    18.5821659893339723
```

Please help

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take out the group by:

```
select 
sum (case when ParameterId = 'AVA (VTI)' then (ResultValue) else 0 end) as 'AVA (VTI)',
sum(case when ParameterId = '2D/Ao Root Diam' then (ResultValue) else 0 end) as '2D/Ao Root Diam'
from DBCREATORS.Parameter as P
where ParameterId 
in ('AVA (VTI)', '2D/Ao Root Diam')
```

Without a group by SQL Server will combine everything into a single row.  Your when clause will keep your values from changing.

You could also look into the [pivot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use sub queries.

```
select
(
    select sum (ResultValue) 
    from DBCREATORS.Parameter as P 
    where ParameterId = 'AVA (VTI)'
) as 'AVA (VTI)',
(
    select sum (ResultValue) 
    from DBCREATORS.Parameter as P 
    where ParameterId = '2D/Ao Root Diam'
) as '2D/Ao Root Diam'
```

This should be a better solution than my previous suggestion.

Comment: This query also produced correct output but  is very slow took 107 seconds as compare and previous query marked answer took 21 seconds